# Excel sum if isnumber for non-contiguous range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, isnumeric

I simply want to sum two cells if at least one of them is a valid number, or display blank if neither of them are. What is the best way to do this? I have read about SUMPRODUCT and tried to use ISERROR to no avail. What I finally came up with works:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(AG6),ISNUMBER(BB6)),(IF(ISNUMBER(AG6),AG6,0)+IF(ISNUMBER(BB6),BB6,0)),"")
```

but I know there must be a more efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also seems to work:

```
=IF(SUM(B6,C6)=0,"",SUM(B6,C6))
```

Tested with your examples.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(B6),ISNUMBER(C6)),SUM(B6,C6),"")
```

Re the non-contiguous requirement - in the example below `B6` and `C6` can be any cells you want.

[image]